# How to forward declare a global variable in corona sdk

Tags: variables, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

i am making a game using corona sdk and i have this problem.
i want to save the game settings like music OFF or ON even after the game is closed.

so i am saving the status on a file. but it is not working.

can any one advise about a solution regarding this.
also i am thinking of a solution but it needs forward declare a global variable. is that possible. or only local variables can be forward declared.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK](https://github.com/robmiracle/Simple-Table-Load-Save-Functions-for-Corona-SDK) and [save and get preferences](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/09/21/introducing-new-preference-storage-features/) - new feature in Corona.